# Trix editor extends paragraph formatting to adjacent paragraphs

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, trix

When you try to insert a picture between two paragraphs, and make the second paragraph a quote, the picture also becomes a quote. The video shows that when you press the quote button, the picture becomes smaller, that is, it becomes part of the quote block. At the same time, on the [official website](https://trix-editor.org/), the editor presented on the page works more predictably and correctly.
[For clarity, I attach a video.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osAQT.gif) JSFiddle [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/tsnkqzd0/1/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/1.3.1/trix.css" integrity="sha512-CWdvnJD7uGtuypLLe5rLU3eUAkbzBR3Bm1SFPEaRfvXXI2v2H5Y0057EMTzNuGGRIznt8+128QIDQ8RqmHbAdg==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/1.3.1/trix.js" integrity="sha512-/1nVu72YEESEbcmhE/EvjH/RxTg62EKvYWLG3NdeZibTCuEtW5M4z3aypcvsoZw03FAopi94y04GhuqRU9p+CQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/1.3.1/trix-core.js" integrity="sha512-H8CbNdhcOBCt62S6eVGAUSiyNx5OGVEVrYIIVs0iIgurgD1+oTA9THTZ1tqxSE9yw9vzfilg83xgyxD467a28g==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
    
  <input id="x" type="hidden" name="content">
  <trix-editor input="x"></trix-editor>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The reason seems to be that the `<span data-trix-cursor-target="left" data-trix-serialize="false"></span>` and `<span data-trix-cursor-target="right" data-trix-serialize="false"></span>` tags do not appear inline and look like full paragraphs even though they are inline in CSS. Attempting to play around with CSS has given no results. Please, help.